# dialog form validat

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery-ui-dialog

how I can call $("#form").validated() function from jquery-ui-dialog ok button???

note: I don't want to use a submit button from form..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it inside the buttons callback:

```
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        buttons: {
            "OK": function() {
                $(this).find('form').validate().form();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What does that `form()` at the end do?

Comment: thank you... I have another question, I f I am using div not form how it will call???

Comment: alex, form() will validate the form.  More info here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/form

Comment: Angela, I haven't tried using the validation plugin without a form tag.  Why not wrap your div with a form tag?  That way, you can follow the official validation documentation provided here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation